# Create dropdown list from another table into my update/delete/add table

Tags: php, mysql, database, lookup, dropdownbox

Im a newbie and working on a project for school

I have a website that lists foods.

I have an update table that allows me to change and add data.

For the food group field I have it cross reference another table called food_group which has the food_group(name) and an id.

When you view the food data you can see the name that it pulls instead of the ID. On the update page I would like a drop down to be in the place of the ID. So you can see the "friendly" name instead of the ID number, but it has to store the ID not the friendly name in the food table.

Website can be found at http://web.nmsu.edu/~jrortiz/ICT458/FINAL/

The code I have is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pw","db");
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}


if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE food SET food_group='$_POST[Food_group]', food='$_POST[Food]',     ph='$_POST[PH]' WHERE food='$_POST[hidden]'";               
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
};

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM food WHERE Food='$_POST[hidden]'";          
mysql_query($DeleteQuery, $con);
};

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO food (Food_group, Food, PH) VALUES     ('$_POST[addGroup]','$_POST[addFood]','$_POST[addPH]')";         
mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);
};



$sql = "SELECT * FROM food";
$myData = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Food Group</th>
<th>Food</th>
<th>PH</th>
<th>Update/Add</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action=updateFood.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='Food_group' value='$record[food_group]'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='Food' value='$record[food]'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='PH' value='$record[ph]'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='update' value='update'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='$record[food]'/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "<form action=updateFood.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='addGroup'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='addFood'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='addPH'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='add' value='add'/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_* Update 12/2/13 10:30pm ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
Ok so if I create a new php page like the following it will work. However, I have no idea how to combine it into the original above... Can anyone help?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

// Connect to the database server
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pw");
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("db",$con);

$sql2="SELECT id, food_group FROM food_group"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql2,$con) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$type=$row["food_group"];
$options.= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['food_group'].'</option>';
};?>

<SELECT NAME=Food_group>
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose</OPTION>
<?php echo $options; ?>
</SELECT>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for all your help! 
Jason

Comment: You are open to SQL injection. Please, escape the input data before you put it into the query.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is nice but I just want to point the following:

There's no need to concatenate this

```
"<td>" . "<input type=text name=Food_group value=" . $record['food_group'] . "         </td>";
```

you can type it like this:

```
echo "<td><input type=text name=Food_group value='$record[food_group]'</td>";
```

also you missed to close your input tag

```
echo "<td><input type=text name=Food_group value='$record[food_group]' /></td>";
```

and another is you need to quote your attribute values , see below

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='Food_group' value='$record[food_group]'</td>";
```

Last thing is that you're open to SQL injection, so you should start learning mysqli and prepared statement

Comment: Thank you for those corrections. This is going to make things much better. By using mysqli is there easy ways to make the dropdowns work now?

Comment: BTW. I edited my original code with your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: What does dropdown accomplish for? to select a method `add/edit/delete`?

Comment: For example> 

select (select food_group from food_group where food_group.id = food.food_group) aa, food,  ph from food;";

For example the food_group for 'Alfalfa Grass' is id# '16' from the food group table. So on my edit page it shows the number '16' instead of 'Vegetables' which is defined in the food_group table. So I was hoping I could have a drop down menu that would list the friendly name of 'Vegetables' while the database uses the id number to reference the two tables.

Comment: If you goto http://web.nmsu.edu/~jrortiz/ICT458/FINAL/ You will see links on the left hand side. Food is the list of food whereas update/add foods give your raw data. I would like my update/add foods page to look "more like" my foods page with the friendly names.So I would like to see a dropdown menu for the Food Group option that cross references the user friendly name from the other table but saves the id# instead

Comment: @JasonOrtiz if you want to give it a friendly name then you should have do joining your database provided that `#id` is primary key for it. Do you mind sharing also your database structure? This is the ideal setup and not just storing names in array for reference

Comment: Table: food
id (primary)
food_group:int
food:varchar(30)
ph:varchar(6)

Table: food_group: varchar(15)
id:int (primary key)

I have a relationship form food_group.id to food.food_group

Comment: I can get a dropdown on a new page using the following. However, I have no idea how to incorporate it all together. I added it to my original post above.